# Adding to a list of Self Referential Structures in C?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linked-list

I'm running into a host of issues trying to make a self-referential list of structs. I'm currently getting an illegal hardware instruction and all I know is that it's something after my print statement following my entry as it prints. Could anyone help point out what I need to work on to get my implementation correct? Thank you.

My add function

```
Employee *employeeListHead = NULL;;

int nodeCount = 0;

void addEmployee(void)
{

    char *name = (char*) malloc(MAX_NAME_LENGTH*sizeof(char));
    char gender;
    int age;
    char *title = (char*) malloc(MAX_JOB_LENGTH*sizeof(char));;

    printf("Enter name: \n");   
    scanf(" %100s", name); 
    scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");

    printf("Enter gender: \n");
    scanf(" %1c", &gender); 
    scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");

    printf("Enter age: \n");
    scanf(" %d", &age); 
    scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");

    printf("Enter job title: \n");
    scanf(" %100s", title); 
    scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");
    
    printf("The employee you've entered is: %s %c %d %s \n", name, gender, age, title);

    Employee *newEmp = (Employee*)malloc(sizeof(Employee));
    
    strcpy(newEmp->name, name);
    strcpy(newEmp->gender, &gender);
    newEmp->age = age;
    strcpy(newEmp->profession, title);
    newEmp->next = NULL;

    if(employeeListHead == NULL)
    {
        employeeListHead = newEmp;
        nodeCount++;
    }
    else
    {   
        Employee *temp = (Employee*)malloc(sizeof(Employee));
        temp = employeeListHead;

        while(temp->next != NULL){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = newEmp;
        nodeCount++;
        free(temp);
    }
        
}
```

struct

```
typedef struct Employee{
    char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
    char gender[2];
    int age;
    char profession[MAX_JOB_LENGTH];
    struct Employee *next; 
} Employee;
```

Comment: Could you add in the Employee struct?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Specifically. questions seeking debugging help must provide a complete [mre]. That is, the smallest amount of complete code that anyone can take exactly as shown to reproduce the problem.

Comment: `strcpy(newEmp->gender, &gender);` is wrong because `gender` is a single character and not a string. Do `newEmp->gender = gender`, assuming the `gender` field is a `char` (which you have not shown).

Comment: Ok, now that you have added the `struct` definition we can say the correct code would be `newEmp->gender[0] = gender; newEmp->gender[1] = '\0';` Alternatively read in `gender` as a string and not a single char and then you can use `strcpy`. Or even better, just read straight into the `newEmp` fields - no point reading into tmp vars and then copying across.

Comment: `Employee *temp = (Employee*)malloc(sizeof(Employee)); temp = employeeListHead;` is a memory leak. And then you `free(temp);` but that's the next-to-last node in the list beause of the loop. Just do `Employee *temp = employeeListHead;` and eliminate the `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: Note that your structures are not self-referential, because a pointer to a thing is not the thing itself.  But also, most people would call your "list of Self Referential Structures" simply a "linked list".

Answer (score 0):

```
char *name = (char*) malloc(MAX_NAME_LENGTH*sizeof(char));
```

You don't need this (and it's a memory leak). Use `char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];` instead.

```
char *title = (char*) malloc(MAX_JOB_LENGTH*sizeof(char));;
```

You don't need this (and it's a memory leak). Use `char title[MAX_JOB_LENGTH];` instead;

```
strcpy(newEmp->gender, &gender);
```

This is wrong. `gender` is not a string (unless it is a zero-length string, which doesn't make a lot of sense). You cannot `strcpy` something that is not a string. OTOH `newEmp->gender` is a string. Either make both of those strings, and use `strcpy`, or make both single characters, and use a simple assignment.

```
    Employee *temp = (Employee*)malloc(sizeof(Employee));
    temp = employeeListHead;
```

Please don't do this. You probably wouldn't do something like this

```
    double x = 2.0 + 76*n + cos(y*2*pi*length);
    x = 42;
```

and the reason is fairly obvious: the first line's computation is just forgotten and thrown away by the assignment in the second line. You could just never have written the first line in the first place, because it doesn't do anything useful whatsoever. Except when `x` is a pointer and the first line calls `malloc`, not only it doesn't do anything useful, it does something harmful: it leaks memory.

```
    Employee *temp = employeeListHead;
```

is all you need, and of course no `free` in the end.